# CSS not working when web page is loaded from network drive

Tags: css, networking

I have written a web page using CSS which works perfectly well when I load it from the computer hard drive, but when I copy it to a network drive it no longer functions, and I am left with just the html.

The code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/regular.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/solid.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style type="text/css">

body { font-size: 80%; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif; }

nav ul {
                  list-style: none; 

                          padding:0;

                          float: left;

                          margin: 0;

                          display: block;

                          text-decoration:none;
}

nav ul ul {
               display: none;
}

nav li {
                  padding: 5px;

                          text-decoration:none;

}

nav li:hover {            background: #ccc;

                          text-decoration:none;

}

nav ul li {               display: block;

                          font-family:helvetica;

                          font-size:20px;

                          background-color:deepskyblue;

                          padding: 10px;

                          text-decoration: none;

                          color: black;

                          width:100%; 

                          height:15px;

                          border: 2px solid black;

                          border-radius:5%;

                          position:relative;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    position: absolute;

                          display: block;

                          top: 0;

                          left: 100%;  

                          width:850px;

                          text-decoration: none;

                          background: #aaa;
}


</style>



</head>


<body>

<h2>Links to useful websites and documents</h2>



<nav>        
  <ul>

     <li>

        <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;"><i class="fas fa-info-circle fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Patient Leaflets</a>

          <ul>

             <li><a href="https://www.talkingtherapies.berkshire.nhs.uk/_store/documents/BH_Joint_TT_Leaflet_sept17_Print_v2.pdf" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;">Talking Therapies Leaflet</a></li>

             <li><a href="https://www.berkshirewestccg.nhs.uk/hcp-section/diabetes-information/diabetes-lifestyle-information/podiatry/foot-care-pathway/" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;">Diabetic foot care pathway and patient leaflets</a></li>

             <li><a href="https://www.berkshirehealthcare.nhs.uk/our-services/adult-healthcare/physiotherapy/" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;">Physiotherapy Exercise Leaflets</a></li>

             <li><a href="http://trend-uk.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Hypo-leaflet-V4.pdf" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;">Hypo Leaflet</a></li>

             <li><a href="https://www.berkshirewestccg.nhs.uk/hcp-section/diabetes-information/diabetes-lifestyle-information/podiatry/foot-care-pathway/" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;">Diabetic Foot Care Leaflets</a></li>

          </ul>

     </li>

     <li>

        <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;"><i class="fas fa-file-prescription fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Prescribing</a>

          <ul>

             <li><a href="https://www.sps.nhs.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/UKMI_QA_How-do-you-switch-between-TCA-SSRI-related-antidepressants_update_Oct-2019.pdf" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;">Guide to Switching Antidepressants</a></li>

             <li><a href="http://westberks.formulary.co.uk/" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;">Berkshire West Formulary</a></li>

             <li><a href="https://www.berkshirewestccg.nhs.uk/about-us/our-responsibilities/medicines-optimisation-team/apc-documents/apc-clinical-documents/" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;">Area Prescribing Committee Guidelines</a></li>

             <li><a href="https://www.sps.nhs.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/UKMI_QA_Vitamin-D-treatment_Jan_2018.docx" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;">Vitamin D Guidelines</a></li>

             <li><a href="http://www.medicinesinpregnancy.org" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;">Medicines in Pregnancy - Information Leaflets</a></li>

             <li><a href="http://www.uktis.org" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;">Medicines in Pregnancy - UK Teratology Information Service</a></li>

             <li><a href="https://www.berkshirewestccg.nhs.uk/media/2906/apc-clindoc-010-hrt-guidance.pdf" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;">HRT Guidelines</a></li>

             <li><a href="http://www.choiceandmedication.org/berkshirehealthcare/printable-leaflets/?results=1&lf=1273&med=&lang=" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;">Handy Charts for Comparing Anxiety/Depression Medications</a></li>

             <li><a href="https://www.berkshirewestccg.nhs.uk/media/3001/apc-clindoc-018-guidelines-for-the-appropriate-prescribing-of-specialist-paediatric-formulas-in-berkshire-west-primary-care.pdf" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;">Formula Milk Prescribing Guidelines</a></li>

          </ul>

     </li>

     <li><a href="Alternatives to Hospital Admission-Nov19.pdf" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;"><i class="fas fa-h-square fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Alternatives to Hospital Admission</a></li>


  </ul>


</nav>

</body>

</html>
```

I'd be really grateful for any pointers as to what I can do to rectify this.
Many thanks.

Just to add, here are some screenshots to clarify the problem.

[image: Screenshot 1]

The above screenshot shows how it is supposed to look, and is what I get when I launch the web page from the hard drive.  It is a menu within a menu, and hovering over the left-hand menu displays the sub-menu items on the right.

[image: Screenshot 2]

The above screenshot shows what happens when it is launched from the network drive.  The code is exactly the same - it just doesn't pick up the CSS at all.

[image]

The above screenshot shows what happens when I remove the "nav" selectors from the CSS (e.g. just "ul ul {display:none;}" instead of "nav ul ul {display:none;}") but still launch it from the network drive, which I think demonstrates that it does recognise the CSS, but for some reason doesn't recognise that it needs to apply it to the section tagged with "nav".  I can't understand why it would do this only when launched from a network location.  Also, you can see that in this third screenshot, although the basic structure works, the icons are missing and the width of the menu block is inconsistent.

Help please!!!

Comment: What happens when you try to open it? Which web browser are you using?

Comment: It's Internet Explorer 11.  If I open it from a network location, I just get the bare HTML without any formatting or drop-down menus.

Comment: Assuming that you've tried to double click your file icon, instead go to 'File' > 'Open' in IE11 and enter the location of your file, that should open it. If it doesn't then you've likely got Enhanced Protected Mode active in IE11. Have you tried in another browser? That would help to troubleshoot.

Comment: Please see edited question above, with new explanatory screenshots.

Comment: Did you try the 'open' > 'file' directly in the browser? did you try another browser? I suspect your operating system is blocking the file as a security measure.

Comment: I did try your suggestions and they made no difference I’m afraid. I suspect it is something more subtle than that though, in view of the rather odd changes when I remove the “NAV” tags.